# Same domain with different extension - redirect

Tags: redirects, dns, https, domain-forwarding

I have website hosted at say `example.com` I would like to have `example.in`, which should redirect users to `example.com`.

So, should I use **domain forwarding** feature that my DNS provides to redirect from `.in` to `.com`? Or should I add just one **A Record** at `.in` DNS management to redirect to same IP as `.com`.

Are there any implications of this if we are using HTTPS (SSL)?

Comment: You should use Apache/Nginx 301 redirect. It tells search engine that website has permanently moved to `xyz.com`.

Comment: It depends what "domain forwarding" actually is - as defined by your DNS provider? You'll need something in DNS (possibly an `A` record) that points `example.in` to the correct host, however, you'll also probably want an external redirect (ie. a 301 redirect that Robert mentions). If "domain forwarding" does this then great. However, if "domain forwarding" is like "framed forwarding" then that is not a good idea.

Comment: As well, it may not be necessary to have a .in domain with a .com as far as can see. You can do it of course. It is like my having .com, .org, and .net all pointing to the same domain. The only advantage I can see is locking in the domain name so that it cannot be used. Otherwise, there is no advantage - at least for me. I rather suspect that .com sites rank rather well for India and that adding .in for SEO value may not work to your advantage. I also do not think it will hurt either.

Comment: Who is your registrar, a 301 is a 301, makes no difference if you host it yourself or use the 3rd party system (like http://www-301.com)